# Codename One - MultipartRequest to send screenshot of the app, error code 400

Tags: codenameone

I can send a file and some extra data to my REST server by a POST request mapped to "/".

This is an example of working HTML code, using this form the server stores a file and some metadata (appID, description):

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
        <table>
            <tr><td>File to upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
        </table>
                <input type="hidden" name="appID" value="uploadForm" />
                <input type="hidden" name="description" value="example of description" />
    </form>
```

I need to send a screenshot of the app using this POST request.

I wrote a method that seems to save correctly the file "screenshot.png" (I found that file in the .cn1 folder used by the Simulator), but the POST request fails with an HTTP Error Code 400 (shown in a Dialog). What's wrong in the following method? Please assume that the previous HTML code works without errors, I expect to do the same with Codename One.

The logs report the following information, the URL of the server is correct:

> [EDT] 0:0:17,736 - Storage URL for POST multipart request: 
>   http://localhost:8090/
>
> [EDT] 0:0:17,738 - Screenshot file to send: 
>   file://home/screenshot.png

```
public static void sendScreenshotToCloud(Form form, String info) {

    if (form == null) {
        form = getCurrentForm();
    }

    Image screenshot = Image.createImage(form.getWidth(), form.getHeight());
    form.revalidate();
    form.setVisible(true);
    form.paintComponent(screenshot.getGraphics(), true);

    ImageIO imgIO = ImageIO.getImageIO();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        imgIO.save(screenshot, out, ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG, 1);
    } catch (IOException err) {
        Log.e(err);
    }
    byte[] ba = out.toByteArray();
    try (OutputStream os = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream("screenshot.png")) {
        os.write(ba);
    } catch (IOException err) {
        Log.e(err);
        Log.sendLog();
    }

    MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();
    request.addResponseListener((e) -> {
        // process the response
        if (e.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            Log.p("Screenshot uploaded to the cloud successfully");
            ToastBar.Status status = ToastBar.getInstance().createStatus();
            status.setMessage("Screenshot sent...");
            status.show();
            UITimer.timer(2000, false, () -> status.clear());
        } else {
            Log.p("ERROR in sending the screenshot to the cloud");
            ToastBar.Status status = ToastBar.getInstance().createStatus();
            status.setMessage("ERROR: cannot send screenshot...");
            status.show();
            UITimer.timer(2000, false, () -> status.clear());
        }
    });
    String url = RestRequest.getInstance().getConnectionRequestStorageURL("");
    String filePath = getAppHomePath()+"screenshot.png";
    Log.p("Storage URL for POST multipart request: \n" + url);
    Log.p("Screenshot file to send: \n" + filePath);
    request.setUrl(url);
    try {
        request.addData("file", filePath, "image/png");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e(ex);
        Log.sendLog();
    }
    request.addArgument("appID", RegisterApp.getAppID());
    // request.addArgument("description", info + Miscellaneous.getAllLogs());
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);

    ToastBar.Status status = ToastBar.getInstance().createStatus();
    status.setMessage("Uploading...");
    status.show();
    UITimer.timer(2000, false, () -> status.clear());
}
```

Comment: This should be identical unless I'm missing something big... It's possible a cookie is needed by the server or something like that. I suggest opening the network monitor and looking at what is sent/received. I also suggest overriding readResponse() and printing out the output which in the case of an error often prints out the error message.